# Database design for Real cash credits/points

Tags: database-design

I want to store credits ($) in the database, where the system will give away a certain amount ($5 for example) for every action made by the customer (e.g. referral, registration, place 2nd order, ...)

How will I go about designing the database tables for storing the credits?

I'm aware that placing a "credits" data field in the "users" table will not be viable, since it will not be secure enough and ensure it's validity.

Another solution I can think of will be creating another table, "transactions", and store all the credit and debits information for each transaction.

Anyone can suggest a better solution to store the credits?

Comment: Transaction table is a must.

Comment: How do I calculate the credits I have for that specific user?

Do I just create a new field (credits) in the 'Users' table and store the latest updated amount in that field

Or, use a SQL Query to get the latest amount from the 'transactions' table, such as "FIND SUM(credits)-SUM(debits) as current_credits... WHERE..."

Comment: Depends on number of transaction u expect. If small, a sum would be suffice. However by adding credit column would be faster. Not sure any drawbacks.